# Align text to the left and right on the same line with CSS

Tags: html, css, text-align

I am working on my about page and having trouble with this.  Trying to align the (years or pending) to the right side of the column.  See image for example.

Top is how it looks now.  Bottom image is how I want it to look.

[image]

Site is located at http://www.eatlovepray.me/portfolio/about-me/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try to use span and then set the style equals 'float:right'

```
<span style="float:right">pending </span>
```

Comment: OMG, thank man.  Took me 3 days playing with css, div styles, margins etc etc and couldn't even pull it off. 

Your method is simple and to the point. Worked perfectly.

Comment: @user3808918 In addition, check out http://jsfiddle.net/N4JZy/ to see it in action. My example uses divs rather than spans but a lot of people got here faster than I did.

Comment: ^ Thanks.  That css also cleans up the mess on my part.  I had a bunch of extra codes that wasn't needed since I copy and pasted a lot of them here and there.

Comment: @user3808918 Please try and avoid inline `style` attributes. Use a `.class` instead.

Comment: @user3808918, what have you got against inline style?  I,personally, find the inline style MUCH easier to follow rather than having to constantly refer back to some internal/external .css style commands.

Answer (score 3):

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4dgaurav/uD37C/)**

css

```
ul {
    list-style: none;
}
#about ul li span {
    float: right;
}
```

html

```
<div id="about">
     <h3><strong>Education</strong></h3>

    <ul>
        <li><strong>Golden West College – Huntington Beach, CA <span>2012-2014</span></strong>

        </li>
        <li>– Associate in Arts Degree – Digital Arts Major <span>(pending)</span>
        </li><br/>
        <li>Certificate of Achievement</li>
        <li>– Graphic Design and Production Option <span>(pending)</span>
        </li><br/>
        <li>Certificate of Specialization</li>
        <li>– Graphic Design Foundation <span>6/2014</span>
        </li>
        <li>– Graphic Design Advanced Production <span>(pending)</span>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Here you go

```
<ul>
    &nbsp;&nbsp;<strong>Golden West College – Huntington Beach, CA <span style="float:right">2012-2014</span></strong><br>
&nbsp; &nbsp; – Associate in Arts Degree – Digital Arts Major <span style="float:right">(pending)</span><br>
<br>&nbsp; Certificate of Achievement<br>
&nbsp; &nbsp; – Graphic Design and Production Option <span style="float:right">(pending)</span><br>
<br>&nbsp; Certificate of Specialization<br>
&nbsp; &nbsp; – Graphic Design Foundation <span style="float:right">6/2014</span><br>
&nbsp; &nbsp; – Graphic Design Advanced Production <span style="float:right">(pending)</span><br>
</ul>
```

Here's a JSFiddle
[Click here](http://jsfiddle.net/Hd8H9/)